# Ускорение работы программы

Tags: c#, winforms, оптимизация

Проблема заключается в том, что моя программа не может справится со своей задачей, слишком много данных проходит один поток данных.

Пример моего кода:

```
// Высчитывание формул для второй таблицы (и сразу записываем)
for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.RowCount - 1; i++)
{
    if (this.dataGridView2.CurrentRow != null)
    {
        dataGridView2.Rows.Add();
        //первый пример
        this.dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value += string.Format("{0:0.###}", Convert.ToDouble((Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView1[2, i].Value) - Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView1[2, 0].Value)) * Convert.ToDouble(textBox1.Text)));
        //второй пример
        this.dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value += string.Format("{0:0.#####}", Convert.ToDouble((Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView1[7, i].Value) - Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView1[7, 0].Value)) / 78));
        //делаем расчёты дополнительных величин
        double poin = Convert.ToDouble((from DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView2.Rows
                                        where row.Cells[3].FormattedValue.ToString() != string.Empty
                                        select Convert.ToDouble(row.Cells[3].FormattedValue)).Max().ToString());
    }
    else
    {
        i--;
        dataGridView2.Rows.RemoveAt(i);
        return;
    }
}
```

У меня есть только две идеи как ускорить код:

- Через async/await
- Через многопоточность

но проблема в том, что я никогда не сталкивался с этим и даже представления не имею как их сюда привинтить... В интернете я видел обучения на примере (*MyWebService*)

На данный момент программа виснет (если много данных обрабатывает), но при этом же процессор нагружен только на 6% (и то 3-4% это посторонние программы) и оперативная память загружается только, когда программа выполнит свою задачу.

Comment: Как данные попадают в DataGridView? может просто проводить операции с этими данными?(не выдергивая их из грида)

Comment: @Dude36 Если ты про DataGridView2, то сначала он берёт несколько значений из DataGridView1 и проводит математику, после чего он добавляет результат в DataGridView2. в DataGridView путём обычного чтение и вставки данных в таблицу из вне (txt file). _А как ты можешь проводить такие операции не выдёргивая из таблицы_?

Comment: Для начала запустите профилировщик и посмотрите где конкретно находится бутылочное горлышко вашей программы.

Comment: Elem Stack, лучше выдернуть значение из грида, поработать с ним и вернуть его обратно, чем вот так. Ресурсов меньше скушает...

Comment: @Dube36 а зачем вообще из GridView вытаскивать, может работать с теми данными, которые были занесены в GridView?

Comment: danilshik экономия ресурсов.

Comment: @Dude36 а почему будет экономия ресурсов? данных же меньше не станет, на оборот, я думаю, если вытаскивать, то это дополнительный гемор для программы, особенно если строк в таблице больше 200тыс.

Comment: @Dude36 экономия каких ресурсов? ОЗУ? Так о какой экономии вы говорите если здесь интерфейс зависает из-за большого количества данных

Comment: вы правы, что - то я сморозил не то, не кидайте камнями )))  вычисления надо производить не с гридом 1 а данными (которые в источнике) , а потом уже их выкладывать в грид 2, во

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я любитель иногда пострадать... кхм... фигнёй. Поэтому держите ваш код с микрооптимизациями:

```
double d = Convert.ToDouble(textBox1.Text);

for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.RowCount - 1; i++)
{
    var cells = dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells;

    if (dataGridView2.CurrentRow != null)
    {
        dataGridView2.Rows.Add();

        cells[0].Value +=
            ((Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView1[2, i].Value) - Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView1[2, 0].Value)) * d)
            .ToString("0.###");

        cells[1].Value +=
            ((Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView1[7, i].Value) - Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView1[7, 0].Value)) / 78)
            .ToString("0.#####");


        double poin = (from DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView2.Rows
                       where row.Cells[3].FormattedValue.ToString() != string.Empty
                       select Convert.ToDouble(row.Cells[3].FormattedValue)).Max();
    }
    else
    {
        dataGridView2.Rows.RemoveAt(i - 1);
        return;
    }
}
```

Что сделано: я обратил внимание, что конвертация `Convert.ToDouble(textBox1.Text)` выполняется многократно в цикле. Вынес это за цикл.

Ввёл переменную `cells`. Не ради перфоманса, а ради сокращения кода.

Убрал все лишние вызовы `Convert.ToDouble`. В том числе из linq-запроса.

Заменил `string.Format` на `ToString`. Метод форматирования *в рантайме* парсит свою строку формата и ищет места подстановки параметров. Из-за этого его производительность весьма печальна.

Примечание: у датагрида и его ячеек есть свойство [DataGridViewCell.Style](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcell.style?view=netframework-4.8). Можно задать его свойство [Format](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcellstyle.format?view=netframework-4.8#System_Windows_Forms_DataGridViewCellStyle_Format) и не нужно будет делать форматирование в коде.

Это всё должно улучшить производительность (но совсем чуть-чуть, конечно же).

---

Выражение `row.Cells[3].FormattedValue.ToString() != string.Empty` вероятно можно заменить на `row.Cells[3].FormattedValue != null`. Это будет быстрее, но нужно точно знать, что там у вас может быть.

Если бы осуществлялась привязка типизированной коллекции (со свойствами типа double), то вызовы `Convert.ToDouble` можно было бы заменить на приведение типа:

```
(((double)dataGridView1[7, i].Value - (double)dataGridView1[7, 0].Value) / 78)
```

Это тоже было бы быстрее.

Но в любом случае, это *микрооптимизации*.

---

Применить распараллеливание к этому коду напрямую невозможно, т. к. он работает с GUI-контролами. А менять их состояние из другого потока *нельзя*. Ставить вызовы `Control.Invoke` и т. п. - убить весь эффект от параллельности.

Поэтому самый правильный выход - не работать с GUI. Как вам уже советовали в комментариях и другом ответе, храните данные в типизированных коллекцих: `List<T>`, например. Код сразу станет быстрее и проще, без всех этих конвертаций. И прикрутить параллельность - раз плюнуть.

Comment: Воу, спасибо тебе большое за разъяснение, теперь я больше знаю про оптимизацию!

Answer (score 2):

Первое, что я бы посоветовал, это разделить логику и представление данных. Сейчас они у Вас слиты воедино (тот же `dataGridView`используется для хранения и манипулирования данными). Думаю, что когда визуальные компоненты будут использоваться только для отображения готовых данных Вы уже получите немалую выгоду по ресурсам.

А, дальше уже нужно смотреть вычислительную сложность алгоритма, асинхронность/распараллеливание и т.д.

> слишком много данных проходит один поток данных.
>
> . . .
>
> У меня есть
>   только две идеи как упростить код:
>
> Через Async или AWait Через много поточность

И то и другое само по себе может избавить Вас от блокировки ("зависания") пользовательского интерфейса, при обработке большого объёма информации (если всё сделаете правильно). С эффективностью алгоритмов и распределением вычислений по потокам Вам нужно будет уже самому разбираться.

Comment: Разделить логику в каком плане? то есть cделать для каждой обработки свой цикл? или я что-то не так понял?

Comment: @ElemStack используйте только для вывода. Все операции по преобразованию из одних данных в другие производите в какой либо структуре данных (двумерные массивы, списки и т.д). Затем можете оптимизировать уже сам алгоритм

Comment: Т.е вы данные подготовили, вывели в GridView, а данные для GridView2 берете не из GridView1, а из подготовленных данных

Comment: Тем самым убирается одна операция (когда берется значение из GridView1)

Comment: @danilshik а будет польза, если я сделаю чистку 1-ой таблицы на время такой работы? И подготовленные данные это, на пример, может быть DataTable (через которую и вводятся данные в gridview1) ?

Comment: @ElemStack а зачем вам первую таблицу очищать? Они же у вас одновременно присутствуют или нет?

Comment: а да, всё верно, это я уже путать начал что-то.